# Multi Threading parallel excution of program in python

Tags: python, multithreading

### server.py

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET ,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print "socket success"

sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

sock.bind(('127.0.0.1',9999))

print "binded success fully"

sock.listen(5)

while True :
     print "waiting for connection"
     conn,addr = sock.accept()
     while True :
         print conn.recv(30)
         data = "Ack for msg1 client sender 1"
         conn.send(data)
         print "data send success"
         print "waiting for responce comming from client sender2"
         print conn.recv(30)
         print "i am receving from client sender3"
         print conn.recv(30)

     conn.close()
sock.close()
```

### client.py

```
import threading
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET ,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print "client socket connection success"


host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 9999

sock.connect((host , port))

print "socket conncection is established"

def fun1(msg ,num) :
        print "msg is ",msg
        for index in range(num) :
                sock.send(msg)
                print "data sent success",index

def fun2(msg ,num) :
        print "msg is ",msg
        for index in range(num) :
                print sock.recv(20)
                print "data rxved successfully"
def fun3(msg ,num) :
        print "msg is ",msg
        for index in range(num) :
                sock.send(msg)
                print "data sent success",index


thread1 = threading.Thread(target=fun1("i am thread1",5))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=fun2("i am thread2",5))
thread3 = threading.Thread(target=fun3("i am thread3",5))

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start()
```

#### client output is

```
client socket connection success
socket conncection is established
client socket connection success
socket conncection is established
msg is  i am thread1
data sent success 0
data sent success 1
data sent success 2
data sent success 3
data sent success 4
msg is  i am thread2
Ack for ms
data rxved successfully
g1 client 
data rxved successfully
sender 1
data rxved successfully
Ack for ms
data rxved successfully
g1 client 
data rxved successfully
msg is  i am thread3
data sent success 0
data sent success 1
data sent success 2
data sent success 3
data sent success 4
data sent success 1
data sent success 2
data sent success 3
data sent success 4
msg is  i am thread2
Ack for msg client sender 1
data rxved successfully
g1 client 
data rxved successfully
sender 1
data rxved successfully
Ack for ms
data rxved successfully
g1 client 
data rxved successfully
msg is  i am thread3
data sent success 0
data sent success 1
data sent success 2
data sent success 3
data sent success 4
```

Actually i want output is like this :

```
client socket connection success
socket conncection is established
msg is  i am thread1
data sent success 0
i am thread2
Ack for msg 1 client sender 1
msg is  i am thread3
data sent success 0

msg is  i am thread1
data sent success 2
i am thread2
Ack for msg 1 client sender 1
msg is  i am thread3
data sent success 2
etc ....

All threads start at the same time but i was failing to achieve the output like this. please any one help on this .All threads has to execute once but i need solution without using any sleep mechanism
```

After one iteration itself therad1 has to send the date to client
                           thread2 has to receive the data from server 
                           thread3 has again sending the data based on thread2 results .
thread3 is dependent on thread2 output .output seems like a linear but i need faster execution.

Comment: The server only has one thread so it can only handle one request at a time.

Comment: Pretty sure Dan's comment is the answer, but it's also worth remembering that Python suffers from the global interpreter lock (https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). Multithreading in Python is beneficial when trying to minimize time wasted waiting for blocking operations (such as disk and network operations), but you will not be using more than 1 core. Sometimes you can get around this by writing your application around using multiprocessing instead (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), or use another language such as Java.